# Regex (RE2) - Return a string of all matches and not just one match

Tags: regex

Dear great StackOverflow community :)

I'm using Google's BigQuery to query and analyze AppEngine's logs.
Trying to create a query that will return all JSON Keys being used by an API Caller, so I'm using "regexp_extract".

So if an API caller sent the following body (which is a line in the log printing the raw request):

```
{"Customers": [{"PhoneNumber": "0599984512"}],"ExpandAssets": true,"IncludeArchivedAssets": false,"TestRedeemConditions": true}
```

I want to capture all JSON Keys, so a basic Regex would be:

```
SELECT
regexp_extract(Log, r'"(\w+)":') as CallerFields,
FROM ...
```

Eventually the above regex matches all JSON Keys but "CallerFields" is now filled with only one match (the first one actually, which is "Customers"),
while I want "CallerFields" be a string which its value will look something like this:

```
Customers,PhoneNumber,ExpandAssets,IncludeArchivedAssets,TestRedeemConditions
```

Due to the fact that I'm using BigQuery, I'm a bit limited and can't find a way to call the Regex in a loop, which is a good solution I found here in many other questions -
My question is, how do you gather all matches and return it as a string, in Regex?
(Google BigQuery uses RE2 Regex engine)

(of course - if you think of a better way achieving my goal, than capturing all matches in regex, let me know)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ["Use JSON functions instead of BigQuery's regular expression functions if working with structured data, as JSON functions are easier to use."](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#json_extract)

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I couldn't find any examples which are relevant to my case (JSON_EXTRACT / JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR), and the Google documentation and examples are very poor - do you have any relevant example to share? In addition - we accept "broken json" on our engine, so if you send invalid input, we know how to fix and ignore (in most cases), I'm afraid using a JSON-dedicated functions won't be good enough for my case